# How to change an xml file elements attributes in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hi I have a class Booking that stores booking information, I have to have BOOKING to look like this

```
<BOOKING partner="CompanyName" transaction="BOOKING" version="1.0">
```

where CompanyName is a variable.
I'm just wondering if anyone can help me add the attributes to the booking element.
I am using vb.net do I add the attributes to the class or do I add them during or after serializing?
if you could help with code that would be great,

Comment: do you have code for this yet?  Are you using a System.XML.XmlTextWriter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class would look like this assuming that's all there is to the node (you didn't close it).

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Class BOOKING
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property partner As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property transaction As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property version As String
End Class
```

Usage

```vb
Dim s = New XmlSerializer(GetType(BOOKING))
```

If it's a string in code

```vb
Dim xml = "<BOOKING partner=""CompanyName"" transaction=""BOOKING"" version=""1.0""/>"
```

Or you can read it from a file

```vb
Using sr As New StreamReader("xmlFileNameAndPath.xml")
    xml = sr.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

The deserialize into your `BOOKING` object

```vb
Dim b As BOOKING = s.Deserialize(New StringReader(xml))
```

You can then edit the object and serialize it back to the original xml

```vb
b.partner = "different company"
Using sw As New StreamWriter("xmlFileNameAndPath.xml")
    s.Serialize(sw, b)
End Using
```

Though in a real xml file you would have an `XmlRoot` element (this solution uses `BOOKING` as the root) then you would be able to have multiple `BOOKING` elements inside that. Hope this gets you rolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Dim swLineItem As New IO.StringWriter()
        Dim xmlWriter As New System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(swLineItem)

 xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
   xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("YourOuterMostElement")
     xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Booking") 
       xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("partner", "CompanyName")
       xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("transaction", "BOOKING")
       xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.0")

     xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
 xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
```