# Trouble Accessing C# object in serialized XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

The following is snippet of an auto-generated class coming from an XML schema:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PeriodEnd", typeof(string), DataType = "nonNegativeInteger")]  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PeriodEndYear", typeof(string), DataType = "nonNegativeInteger")]  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PeriodStart", typeof(string), DataType = "nonNegativeInteger")]  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PeriodStartYear", typeof(string), DataType = "nonNegativeInteger")]  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SelectionEndDate", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType = "date")]  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SelectionStartDate", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType = "date")]  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
```

My problem is, I need to hard code the "SelectionEndDate" and the "SelectionStartDate"

The autogenerated class created an array of objects called Items.

On my main program, I want to do something like

```
af.Header.SelectionCriteria.Items.SelectionStartDate = datevariable
```

Any advice on how I can get to modify these fields?

The xml looks something like this

```
<Header>
        <AuditFileVersion>2.01</AuditFileVersion>
        <AuditFileCountry>LU</AuditFileCountry>
        <AuditFileDateCreated>2014-08-01</AuditFileDateCreated>
        <SoftwareCompanyName>MyCompany</SoftwareCompanyName>
        <SoftwareID>MyCompany</SoftwareID>
        <SoftwareVersion>2.0</SoftwareVersion>
        <Company>
            <RegistrationNumber>1234 567 891</RegistrationNumber>
            <Name>MyCompany</Name>
            <Address>
                <City>MyCity</City>
                <PostalCode>1234</PostalCode>
            </Address>
            <Contact>
                <ContactPerson>
                    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                </ContactPerson>
                <Telephone />
            </Contact>
            <TaxRegistration>
                <TaxRegistrationNumber>XX12334</TaxRegistrationNumber>
            </TaxRegistration>
            <BankAccount>
                <IBANNumber>132456</IBANNumber>
            </BankAccount>
        </Company>
        <DefaultCurrencyCode>EUR</DefaultCurrencyCode>
        <SelectionCriteria>
            <SelectionStartDate>2014-07-01</SelectionStartDate>
            <SelectionEndDate>2014-07-31</SelectionEndDate>
        </SelectionCriteria>
        <TaxAccountingBasis>Invoice</TaxAccountingBasis>
    </Header>
```

Got it resolved by using

```
af.Header.SelectionCriteria = new SelectionCriteriaStructure();
            af.Header.SelectionCriteria.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType1[]{ItemsChoiceType1.SelectionStartDate,ItemsChoiceType1.SelectionEndDate};
            af.Header.SelectionCriteria.Items = new object[] { new DateTime(year, month, 01), new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month)) };
```

Comment: Can you share the XML too please.

Comment: Sure, this is the header section of the XML, I am trying to access <SelectionStartDate> and <SelectionEndDate>

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. Your usage would be more like

```
af.Header.SelectionCriteria.SelectionStartDate = datevariable
```

Note you don't need the `Items` portion. Not sure what you mean by hard coded in this case, but you can override the get method of any of the properties you wish to hard-code, so you always get the same value regardless of the XML.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SelectionCriteria criteria;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SelectionCriteria));
            // this string should be the element you want to deserialize
            string xml =
                "<SelectionCriteria " + 
                "PeriodEnd=\"1\" " +
                "PeriodEndYear=\"2\" " + 
                "PeriodStart=\"3\" " + 
                "PeriodStartYear=\"4\" " +
                "SelectionEndDate=\"2014-07-31\" " +
                "SelectionStartDate=\"2014-07-01\"/>";
            criteria = (SelectionCriteria)serializer.Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
        }

    }

    [XmlRoot("SelectionCriteria")]
    public class SelectionCriteria
    {
        [XmlAttribute("PeriodEnd")]
        public string PeriodEnd { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("PeriodEndYear")]
        public string PeriodEndYear { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("PeriodStart")]
        public string PeriodStart { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("PeriodStartYear")]
        public string PeriodStartYear { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("SelectionEndDate")]
        public DateTime SelectionEndDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("SelectionStartDate")]
        public DateTime SelectionStartDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have answered a similar question before: [How to change an xml file elements attributes in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431411/how-to-change-an-xml-file-elements-attributes-in-vb-net/23431631#23431631)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Actually I can't access af.Header.SelectionCriteria.SelectionStartDate :/

Comment: What do you mean? It's your code; you can [set the] access [level to] anything.

Comment: I got it working without touching the autogenerated code af.Header.SelectionCriteria = new SelectionCriteriaStructure();
            af.Header.SelectionCriteria.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType1[]{ItemsChoiceType1.SelectionStartDate,ItemsChoiceType1.SelectionEndDate};
            af.Header.SelectionCriteria.Items = new object[] { new DateTime(year, month, 01), new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month)) };